# Is there a way to get the HTTP request information in Jenkins from a GitLab webhook?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I have a Jenkins pipeline that is invoked from a GitLab webhook. I need to get merge request title, and see that it is available in the merge request information in the HTTP request payload. Is there a way to grab this information easily in the pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

We found an answer to this. On webhook execution, the GitLab plugin makes request information available to the pipeline via the env variable. Retrieving the merge request title can be done like so:

`echo ${env.gitlabMergeRequestTitle}`